# only display first column?

Tags: php, html-table

This code shows every info from an XML. I want to only display row number one (first from/to, symbol temperature etc)

```
  <?php
  $url = ('https://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/oslo/oslo/oslo/varsel_time_for_time.xml');

    $feed = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Can not connect to server');
    $result = array();
    foreach ($feed->forecast->tabular->time as $content) {
        array_push($result, [ "from" => (string)$content['from'],
            "to" => (string)$content['to'],
            'symbol' => (string)$content->symbol['name'],
            'symbol-icon' => (string)$content->symbol['var'],
            'temperature' => (string)$content->temperature['value'],
            'windDirection' => (string)$content->windDirection['name'],
            'windSpeed' => (string)$content->windSpeed['mps'],
            'windType' => (string)$content->windSpeed['name'],
        ]);
    }
  ?>
<button class="collapsible"><div class="tbl-content">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($result as $value) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td>Oslo</td>
             <td><?php echo date("j. M", strtotime($value['from'])); ?> kl.<?php echo date("G", strtotime($value['from'])); ?></td>
             <td><img src="http://yr.github.io/weather-symbols/png/100/<?php echo $value['symbol-icon'];?>.png" /></td>
             <td><?php echo $value['temperature'] ?> °C</td>
             <td><?php echo $value['windType'] ?>, <?php echo $value['windSpeed'] ?> m/s fra <?php echo $value['windDirection'] ?></td>
             <td>Longtherm</td>
             <td>Hour</td>
         </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div></button>
```

quite unexperienced, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just remove the columns you don't need. It will only print what you tell it to print.

Comment: maybe badly explained from me. This code outputs many rows (it is dynamic so not always the same amount, it loops thought to the point its reached the end of the XML).  I want to set a limit on how many rows that can be output, but if I could easily change the limit it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one of the rows? Remove the foreach! Just use `$result[0]` in place of `$value`. :-)

A defined number of rows? Use a for loop:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {
    $value = $result[$x];
    // etc
}
```